# Is it possible to encrypt the database password in the Joomla configuration file?

Tags: joomla-3.6, security

Is it possible to encrypt the database password in the Joomla configuration file?

Example : 
change  public $password = 'xxxxxx';

by : $password = hash;

Answer (score 2):

No. But what you can do if you want to hide this information is to place the `configuration.php` outside the `public_html` folder (if you want someone who has access to the `public_html` directory not be able to read the `configuration.php` file).

However, this, in my opinion, is a futile experiment, since if the person with access to the `public_html` folder can upload a PHP file which can read the `configuration.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

Dont waste your time. If someone has access to your site in order to read that file then they can do anything that they want to do.